# Not able to get location via google maps API

Tags: geolocation

I am trying to get the location of user via `Geolocation` API, it was working fine till yesterday but today i am getting as "Unable to get Location" for every attempt

Script used for API is

```
 <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
          var geocoder;

              if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
            } 
            //Get the latitude and the longitude;
            function successFunction(position) {
                var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                var lng = position.coords.longitude;

                      //var num = parseFloat(lat);
                    //var str = num.toFixed(10);
                    //str = str.substring(0, str.length-7);
                    $('#yourlat').val(lat);$('#yourlat1').val(lat);
                    //var num1 = parseFloat(lng);
                    //var str1 = num1.toFixed(10);
                    //str1 = str1.substring(0, str1.length-7);
                    $('#yourlong').val(lng);$('#yourlong1').val(lng);
                codeLatLng(lat, lng)
            }

            function errorFunction(){
                alert("Geocoder failed");
            }

              function initialize() {
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
              }

              function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {

                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                var addressget ='';
                geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                  console.log(results)
                    if (results[1]) {
                     //formatted address
                     //alert(results[0].formatted_address)
                     addressget = results[0].formatted_address;
                       $('#yourcity').html(addressget);
                       $('#yourcitys').val(addressget);
                    //find country name
                         for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                        for (var b=0;b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

                        //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                            if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                                //this is the object you are looking for
                                city= results[0].address_components[i];
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    //city data
                    var stateget ='';
                    stateget = city.short_name + " " + city.long_name;
                         $('#yourstate').html(stateget);
                    } 

                    else {
                      alert("We are not able to get your location..");
                    }
                  } 
                  else {
                    alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
                  }
                });
              }

        </script>
```

I am calling function on bodyload

```
     <body onload="initialize()">
```

Everytime i allow to get location it gives error as `We are not able to get your location..`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking what the status variable is indicating. the valuesfor the class google.maps.GeocoderStatus can be found from the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1)